# Is translation continouos in Schwartz space?

Tags: schwartz-space

It is true that translation is continuous in Schwartz Space {S}($\mathbb{R}$) with its topology?, in other words, I'm trying to prove that if $\phi \in {S}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ then the function $\phi(\cdot-y)$ converges to $\phi$ in $S\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.
So I have to prove that for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$.
\begin{equation*}
     \lim _{ y\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left\| { T }_{ y }\left( \phi \right) -\phi \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,\beta  } } =0.
 \end{equation*}
This is my attempt.
It is known that fourier transformation is continuous in Schwartz,so it is enough to prove my idea that the fourier transformation  of $T_y(\phi)$ will converge to $\phi$ in Schwartz. 
How
\begin{equation*}
     \widehat { { T }_{ y }\left( \phi  \right) }  \left( \xi  \right) =e^{ -i\xi y }\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right), 
 \end{equation*}
I have to prove that
\begin{equation*}
   \lim _{ y\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left\| e^{ -i\xi y }\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right) -\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right)  \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,\beta  } } =0.
 \end{equation*}
Thus, 
 \begin{align}
     \nonumber\left| { \xi  }^{ \alpha  }{ \left( e^{ -i\xi y }\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right) -\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right)  \right)  }^{ \left( \beta  \right)  } \right|& \le \sum _{ j=0 }^{ \beta  }{ \left| { \left( e^{ -i\xi y }-1 \right)  }^{ \left( j \right)  } \right|  } \left| { \xi  }^{ \alpha  }{ \widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right)  }^{ \left( \beta -j \right)  } \right| \\\nonumber &\le C\sum _{ j=0 }^{ \beta  }{ \left| { \left( e^{ -i\xi y }-1 \right)  }^{ \left( j \right)  } \right|  } \\ \nonumber&\le C{ \left( \sum _{ j=1 }^{ \beta  }{ \left| { \left( -iy \right)  }^{ j } \right|  } +\left| 1-e^{ -i\xi y } \right|  \right)  }
 \end{align}
Then, the function $\left| 1-e^{ -i\xi y } \right|  $ is continous and periodic, so its maximun exists,and that follows

\begin{align}
     \nonumber\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left| { \xi  }^{ \alpha  }{ \left( e^{ -i\xi y }\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right) -\widehat { \phi  } \left( \xi  \right)  \right)  }^{ \left( \beta  \right)  } \right|&\le C{ \left( \sum _{ j=1 }^{ \beta  }{ \left| { \left( -iy \right)  }^{ j } \right|  } +\left| 1-e^{ -iz y } \right|  \right)  }
 \end{align}
where z is where the function gets its maximum, then i take the limit when y->0, and the prove is finished.

Comment: Please define your notation. What does $\|\,\|_{\alpha,\beta}$ mean?

Comment: sorry, it means the seminorm in Schwartz, $f\in S\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ if only if $f\in {C}^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ and \begin{equation*}
                 { \left\| f \right\|  }_{ \alpha ,\beta  }: = \underset { x\in \mathbb{R} }{ \sup } \left| { x }^{ \alpha  }{ f }^{ \left( \beta  \right)  }\left( x \right)  \right| <+\infty.
            \end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $f$ for $\phi.$ Let $m,n\in \{0,1,2\dots \}.$ We want to show

$$\sup_x |x|^m|D^n(f(x-y)-f(x))| \to 0$$

as $y\to 0.$ Now $D^n (f(x-y)-f(x))$ $ = D^nf(x-y)-D^nf(x).$ And we know $D^nf \in \mathcal S.$ So it's enough to show that if $g\in  \mathcal S,$ then

$$\tag 1 \sup_x |x|^m|g(x-y)-g(x))| \to 0.$$

By the MVT we have $g(x-y)-g(x) = g'(c)(-y)$ for some $c$ between $x-y$ and $x.$ Thus

$$|g(x-y)-g(x))|\le \left (\sup_{z\in B(x,|y|)}|g'|\right)|y|.$$

So we'll be done if we show

$$|x|^m\left (\sup_{z\in B(x,|y|)}|g'|\right)$$

is bounded independent of $x.$ Fix $x,$ and let $z\in B(x,|y|).$ Then $z=x+t,$ where $|t|\le |y|.$ We have

$$|x|^m|g'(x+t)| \le (|x+t| + |t|)^m|g'(x+t)|$$ $$ \le (2^m|x+t|^m + 2^m|y|^m)|g'(x+t)|.$$

Because $g \in \mathcal S,$ $|x+t|^m|g'(x+t)|$ is bounded independent of $x,$ and so is $|y|^m|g'(x+t)|.$ We thus have desired boundedness, giving the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand how you get the first inequality, can you explain me, please?

Comment: That's the standard mean value inequality. I edited my answer as there was a bit of a mistake in it. This one is clearer I hope.