# Translation is continuous in space of test functions.

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and consider translation by $x_{0}$

$$t_{x_{0}}:C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\to C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$

defined by $t_{x_{0}}=\varphi(\cdot-x_{0}).$

Show that $t_{x_{0}}$ is linear and continuous, and $t_{x_{0}}$ can be extended to continous linear application $S(\mathbb{R}^{n})\to S(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$

My attempt: $t_{x_0}$ is linear its trivial. Now, let $\{\varphi_{j}\}\subset C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\varphi_{j}\to \varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ in topology of this space. That is, exist $K\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ compact such that $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi_{j})\subset K, \ \operatorname{supp}(\varphi)\subset K;$

And for all $\displaystyle\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}^{n}: \lim_{j\to\infty}\sup_{x\in K} |\partial^{\alpha}\varphi_{j}(x)-\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|=0.$

Now consider the compact $\{x_{0}\}+K$, we have $\operatorname{supp}(t_{x_{0}}(\varphi_{j}))\subset x_{0}+K$ and $\operatorname{supp}(t_{x_{0}}(\varphi))\subset x_{0}+K$

And for all $\displaystyle\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}^{n}: \lim_{j\to\infty}\sup_{x\in x_{0}+ K} |\partial^{\alpha}\varphi_{j}(x)-\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|=0.$

Therefore $t_{x_{0}}(\varphi_{j})\to t_{x_{0}}(\varphi).$

It's correct? And for second part, can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to define $t_{x_0}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @md2perpe the same way? Just substute $\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ by $\varphi \in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and use topology of Schwartz space. I saw this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975658/is-translation-continouos-in-schwartz-space. My proof for case in $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is correctly?

Comment: Your proof looks correct. As you write, linearity is trivial, and continuity is just about changing $K$ to $x_0+K$.

Comment: Regarding the extension to $\mathcal{S},$ I think that you should show that if $t_{x_0}\varphi_j \to t_{x_0}\varphi$ in $C^\infty_0$ then $t_{x_0}\varphi_j \to t_{x_0}\varphi$ also in $\mathcal{S}.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you, sir. I'll try here!